# Dll EntryPoint DLL_PROCESS_DETACH not called, after application calls MkParseDisplayNameEx

Tags: c, windows

I have a problem with a dll, which is static loaded by an application.

Normally, when closing the app, the Dll EntryPoint is called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, so a function for unregister the application is executed.
If I close the application after calling `MkParseDisplayNameEx` in the application, the Dll EntryPoint is not called.

This happens only when on the Windows system McAfee virus protection is installed.

When `MkParseDisplayNameEx` is called in the application, many Dlls are loaded by Windows and the virus protection into the memory space of the application.

I can reduce the problem to the blframeworkrt.dll from McAfee.
If I get the module handle of the dll in the application (with `GetModuleHandle`) and call `FreeLibrary` with the received handle, the problem could not reproduced.

But I think, this is not a good solution.

```c
/*DLL-Code:*/

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyTest(void);//only for demonstration

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        MessageBox(0, "DLL_PROCESS_DETACH", "Info", MB_OK);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

```c
/*App-Code:*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestApp.h"
#include "urlmon.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int MyTest(void);

void SomeFunction(void);

void SomeFunction(void)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) exit(0);
    IBindCtx* pBindCtx;
    hr = CreateBindCtx(NULL, &pBindCtx);
    if (FAILED(hr)) exit(0);
    OLECHAR string[] = L"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2";
    ULONG ulParsed;
    IMoniker* pMoniker;
    hr = MkParseDisplayNameEx(pBindCtx,
        string,
        &ulParsed,
        &pMoniker
    );
    if (FAILED(hr)) exit(0);
    pMoniker->Release();
    pBindCtx->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Maybe someone had an problem like this and has an other solution.